# 複数枚のpngを一つのtiffにまとめる方法が分かりません。

Tags: python, 画像, pillow

Pillowを用いることで出来ることは調べて分かったのですが、それ以上が分かりません。

Comment: どんな風にまとめるかでやり方も変わってくると思うのですが、何かやりたいことのイメージを追記してみてください。[Save multiple images in a tiff file #3636](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3636)

Answer (score 2):

`img`フォルダのpngファイルをまとめてtiffにするサンプルコードです。
[Qiitaの参考記事](https://qiita.com/machisuke/items/0ca8a09d79bd5eba3cf3)

```
import glob
from PIL import Image

dir = r"img/*.png"      # pngファイルのワイルドカード
save_path = "hoge.tif"  # 出力ファイルパス

stack = [Image.open(p) for p in glob.glob(dir)]

stack[0].save(save_path, compression="tiff_deflate", save_all=True, append_images=stack[1:])
```